# Video in popup box

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to embed a youtube code inside a popup box when the user clicks a link like this:

[image]

However another user is having a problem on Firefox when the video is not even embed in the popup:

[image]

The user is having the problem in Firefox but when I tested it in Firefox everything was OK.

Is there something in the settings of Firefox that he has and I don't?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Creating a modal window with HTML5 &amp; CSS3</title>

    <style>
    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 560px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }

    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -10px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }

    .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
    h2
    {
        text-align:center;  
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Youtube Video</h2>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/98H2x9BjUxE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a jsFiddle to solve this http://jsfiddle.net/sMpcL/1/

I've added the following: -

```
.modalDialog { display: none; }
.modalDialog:target { display: block; }
```

It's working for me in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Without those 2 lines did it work for you on Firefox?

Comment: this issue occurs in Firefox 17 for example.

Comment: Without those two lines it was not working in my Firefox (v26)

Comment: @loops Just a question: Does the above code fix it for Firefox 17?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique yes. visibility:hidden also works. Iceweasel here.